# Typesafe activator(Play with Java) eclipse command can't load Jars in Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, playframework, typesafe-activator

I've been playing around with Play 2.0 since last few weeks. I used "play eclipsify" & imported the project to Eclipse. Everything went perfect. All the jars were loaded into IDE as `"Refrenced Libraries"` from Repository folder.
Now i've installed typesafe activator & using `Play 2.3`. I again used `"activator eclipse"` command. But now it doesn't load jars from the project. No refrenced libraries in IDE. It picks up all the jars, but from  `/root/.ivy2/cache/further_path_for_each_jar`. This leads to all the jars missing.
Apart from manually giving path of each of those libraries, What's the solution?
Sorry if re-post. I didn't find my solution anywhere.

Thanks & Regards. :)

Comment: Seems like you start on of the programs (eclipse or activator) as user `root`.

Comment: So how does it affect? @dr0i

Comment: Programs look at their home directory. So eclipse looks at the jars residing in its user home directory. "activator eclipse" looks in its users home directory. (it boils down if you really start these both programs with dfiferent users. You haven't provided this information so this is just a guess.) @durlabh-sharma

Answer (score 0):

you could try:
activator clean compile, then
activator eclipse. 
sometimes I delete the project and re-import it.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried like this to load the jars into my application for eclipse juno ide configuration and it's loaded all the jars and worked fine:

in command prompt: go to your application path and then go to your play installed folder and then give the entry like this:

```
play eclipse with-source=true .
```