# How to import a typesafe-activator app as a project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, typesafe-activator

I've just been giving a glance to typesafe activator and I've been rather amazed by this bundle -- a pretty goo idea actually! :) From my humble opinion the web interface just comes with a minor lack which makes it not that convenient to use for more than a Hello World project: why don't we have autocompletion?

As a minimal (non)working example I've created a template app hello-akka in Java (from the same template) and I've performed `activator clean compile` then `activator eclipse`.

```
$ activator clean compile
[info] Loading project definition from ~/hello-akka/project
[info] Updating {file:~/hello-akka/project/}hello-akka-build...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Set current project to hello-akka (in build file:~/hello-akka/)
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed 07-May-2015 12:37:15
[info] Updating {file:~/hello-akka/}hello-akka...
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source and 1 Java source to ~/hello-akka/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[success] Total time: 5 s, completed 07-May-2015 12:37:20
$ activator eclipse
[info] Loading project definition from ~/hello-akka/project
[info] Set current project to hello-akka (in build file:~/hello-akka/)
[info] About to create Eclipse project files for your project(s).
[info] Successfully created Eclipse project files for project(s):
[info] hello-akka
```

Alas! When I import the project within Eclipse, it doesn't load jars from the `repository` folder :'( . For instance, in the file hello-akka/src/test/java/HelloAkkaTest.java, the very first import `import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration;` is not resolved. Eclipse suggestions are `scala.xml.*` but it doesn't know at all about `scala.concurrent.*`.

Of course I could import jars manually each time but it's not very handy. I think it's weird because I get the same result in graphical mode when I click on "generate an Eclipse project". I don't see what I've done in the wrong way. I'm aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26764441/typesafe-activatorplay-with-java-eclipse-command-cant-load-jars-in-eclipse-id) but it hasn't been solved. I'm running on GNU/Linux and I've installer sbt as I've seen it's used by activator.

So, would you know how to properly set typesafe-activator for an Eclipse project? Thanks in advance for any firther reply!! :D